# What is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{E} = \{F \subset \mathbb{R} \ \text{such} \ \text{that} \ F \ \text{is} \ \text{finite} \}$. I am trying to find $\mathcal{M} (\mathcal{E})$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}$. After some experimentations I found the set $\mathcal{C} = \{C \subset \mathbb{R}: C \ \text{or} \ \mathbb{R}-C \ \text{is} \ \text{countable} \}$ is the set I am looking for.

Now I have managed to show that $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, but I stuck on proving that $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$. I appreciate idea and hint.

Comment: I "accidently" wrote a full proof as answer. If you want to think yourself first, consider this hint: how can you show that no countable set can be missing from $\mathcal M(\mathcal E)$? The key are the countable unions.

Comment: Which direction are you stuck on, $\mathcal M(\mathcal E)\subseteq\mathcal C$ or $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal M(\mathcal E)?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Proof*.

Assume there is a smaller $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal C'\subset \mathcal C$ which contains $\mathcal E$ but also lacks the countable set $C\in \mathcal C$. Because $C$ is countable there is an enumeration $\{c_n\}$ of all the elements of $C$. Because $\mathcal E$ contains all finite sets, $\{c_n\}$ belongs to $\mathcal C'$ for all $n$. But then $\mathcal C'$ must contain

$$\bigcup_n \{c_n\}=C.$$

Contradiction. Note that if some co-countable set $\bar C$ is missing from $\mathcal C'$, so is the countable set $C:=\Bbb R-\bar C$. $\square$

Comment: Thanks for your help @M. Winter! Maybe it is because I missed something obvious, I am confused about the $\mathcal{C}^{\prime}$ must contain $C$ part. Isn't $\mathcal{E}$ (contained in $\mathcal{C}^{\prime}$) a collection of sets but $C$ just a set? How does $\mathcal{C}^{\prime}$ contain $C$?

Comment: @ywa136 I do not fully understand your concern. If $\mathcal E$ (and also $\mathcal C'$) are collections of sets and $C$ is a set why does it seem strange that $C\in \mathcal C'$? Is there a problem with the term "contains" and whether it means $\in$ or $\subset$?

Comment: Yes I guess so, I messed up the $\in$ with $\subset$. It is clear now. Thank you! @M. Winter